# Disable one option in excel VBA combobox/listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, disable

**Stainless Steel Plumbing Selected**
[image]

**Jacket Material Options**
[image]

I have several comboboxes where the available options depend on the selection in another combobox, but only in certain situations. For example, if stainless steel plumbing is selected then the jacket *can't* be carbon steel.

Is there a way to disable carbon steel as an option when stainless plumbing is selected?

Comment: Remove that option from the list when Stainless is selected.

Comment: @TimWilliams That is one way of disabling the option. How would I do that?

Comment: That would probably depend on how you populated the list in the first place.  Plenty of similar posts on this topic to be found here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+dependent+combobox   "dependent combobox" is the term to Google for.

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dependent-combo-boxes.html Dependent combobox is the key I needed! Not exactly disabling an option, more repopulating the list, but it accomplished the right thing. Thank you!